# Как одной строкой получить элемент массива, возвращаемого функцией?

Tags: php, массивы

Пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное:

```
function arr() {
    return array(0 => 'asd');
}

function test() {
    return arr()[0];
}
```

Получаю `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`
Есть варианты получения элемента массива в одну строчку?

Comment: Приведенный код работает как минимум в 5.5.11

Comment: В PHP 5.4.37 код работает без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, такая возможность появилась только с php 5.4
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

```
// в PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// ранее делали так
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```

Меня спасла функция `current()`:

```
return current(arr());
```